# ASP.NET 4.0- accessing a webpage inside folder in the application

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

I am using ASP.NET 4.0. I have a folder named `pup`. There is webpage called `login.aspx` under that folder.  When users try to go the `login.aspx` page, I redirect them to another page called `InvalidPage.aspx`.

When I run my application from local and type the url `localhost:2388/pup/login.aspx`, the page `login.aspx` is not redirected to the `InvalidPage.aspx`. But when I type `localhost:2388/PUP/login.aspx`, it does work.  Here the name of the folder is uppercase. Does the case matter? How can I make the URl to ignore the case?

Answer (score 0):

URL's aren't case sensitive in IIS, but where is the redirection logic?  Are you doing a string comparison somewhere when deciding to do the redirection?  That is case-sensitive and may be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the web config file:

```
<rules> 
<rule name="Convert to lcase" stopProcessing="false"> 
<match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false"/> 
<conditions> 
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$"/> 
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent"/> 
</rule> 
</rules>
```